# CSS transition isn't applying to div on click with plain JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that contains some text and a button. By default the div has a max-height of 150px. On click of the button the div expands to be 100% max-height.

The transition applied to the class isn't applying to the div and the height just jumps down, rather than sliding/expanding. I'm using max-height instead of height as I thought that was what was needed, but perhaps I'm doing this wrong?

There also seems to be a delay when clicking the button again to close the div, any idea why this might be?

Any advise would be most appreciated!

```js
var exEl = document.querySelector('.expanding-overflow');

if(typeof(exEl) != 'undefined' && exEl != null){
  var btn = document.querySelector('.expanding-overflow .btn');

  btn.addEventListener("click", toggle);

  function toggle() {
    if (exEl.classList.contains('expanded')) {
      exEl.classList.remove('expanded');
    } else {
      exEl.classList.add('expanded');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.expanding-overflow {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out; }
  .expanding-overflow .overlay {
    background: rgb(251,249,247);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(251,249,247,1) 0%, rgba(251,249,247,0.500437675070028) 50%, rgba(251,249,247,0) 100%);
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99; }
    .expanding-overflow .overlay a.btn {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; } 

.expanding-overflow.expanded {
  max-height: 100%; } }
```

```html
<div class="expanding-overflow">
  <div class="overlay">
    <a class="btn">View full</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras risus mi, ultricies sit amet dolor at, facilisis molestie ante. Vestibulum venenatis et odio id feugiat. Phasellus eget imperdiet augue. Donec aliquet ante at faucibus fringilla. Nullam urna magna, dignissim a ante congue, blandit vehicula tellus. Morbi mattis elit non ex tincidunt, ut mattis nisi sagittis. Maecenas fringilla nisl lobortis nulla ultricies, et gravida nisl rutrum. Vestibulum congue ante felis, eu dapibus erat ultrices sit amet. Cras bibendum consequat venenatis.</p>

    <p>Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam faucibus nibh tincidunt magna porta feugiat. Donec venenatis, justo vel porttitor rutrum, elit eros fringilla tellus, eget fringilla odio mi quis tellus. Quisque rhoncus finibus erat, a mattis libero vulputate sit amet. Proin ut tristique leo. Integer interdum, urna nec elementum imperdiet, tortor odio vehicula nisi, ut porttitor libero urna dapibus neque. Sed lacus ex, dignissim nec mauris varius, bibendum elementum nibh. Morbi quis erat at ipsum sollicitudin accumsan nec et ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris et consequat nisi. Sed id sem vitae odio semper sollicitudin. Integer dapibus est vel semper ultrices. Vivamus sagittis lobortis odio, vel tincidunt nisl tempus id. Nullam gravida vestibulum efficitur. Ut sed ligula sit amet quam fermentum efficitur. Vivamus eu sem a ligula suscipit lacinia.</p>

    <p>Praesent a dolor finibus, porttitor est in, hendrerit eros. Pellentesque dui mauris, vehicula euismod ex et, tempus viverra metus. Vivamus molestie, erat non consectetur dapibus, sapien magna sollicitudin orci, vitae porta sem tellus nec nulla. Mauris non mauris quis urna vulputate cursus a eget sem. Vestibulum ac urna dictum, aliquet arcu sed, aliquam velit. Sed id bibendum dolor, eget semper tellus. Fusce aliquam ex quis mauris laoreet, et tincidunt sapien feugiat. Pellentesque sapien leo, faucibus non sapien sit amet, tristique tristique dui. Praesent ultrices blandit tellus, ac volutpat neque laoreet eget. Proin lobortis mauris vel sem eleifend sollicitudin. Vestibulum tempor fermentum elit, nec condimentum metus ultrices in. Donec quis laoreet erat, eu lacinia nibh. Nam eleifend neque vel ipsum lacinia venenatis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with `max-height` or `height`, the problem is that you try to transition from `px`value to `%` value and that doesn't work.

You can use `calc(150px + 0%)` this ( seems like ) it transforms the px value into a % one. So now you transition from % to % and it works.

For that to work you need to set a height to the parent of the element. If it doesn't have a parent, add `html, body { height: 100% }`  like in the snippet below.

Let me know if this is what you were looking for :d

```js
var exEl = document.querySelector('.expanding-overflow');

if(typeof(exEl) != 'undefined' && exEl != null){
  var btn = document.querySelector('.expanding-overflow .btn');

  btn.addEventListener("click", toggle);

  function toggle() {
    if (exEl.classList.contains('expanded')) {
      exEl.classList.remove('expanded');
    } else {
      exEl.classList.add('expanded');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {/* or expanding-overflow wrapper */
  height:100%;
  }
.expanding-overflow {
  position: relative;
  height: calc(0% + 150px);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: height 0.5s ease-out;
}

.expanding-overflow .overlay {
  background: rgb(251, 249, 247);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(251, 249, 247, 1) 0%, rgba(251, 249, 247, 0.500437675070028) 50%, rgba(251, 249, 247, 0) 100%);
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
}

.expanding-overflow .overlay a.btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.expanding-overflow.expanded {
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="expanding-overflow">
  <div class="overlay">
    <a class="btn">View full basket</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras risus mi, ultricies sit amet dolor at, facilisis molestie ante. Vestibulum venenatis et odio id feugiat. Phasellus eget imperdiet augue. Donec aliquet ante at faucibus fringilla. Nullam urna magna, dignissim a ante congue, blandit vehicula tellus. Morbi mattis elit non ex tincidunt, ut mattis nisi sagittis. Maecenas fringilla nisl lobortis nulla ultricies, et gravida nisl rutrum. Vestibulum congue ante felis, eu dapibus erat ultrices sit amet. Cras bibendum consequat venenatis.</p>

<p>Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam faucibus nibh tincidunt magna porta feugiat. Donec venenatis, justo vel porttitor rutrum, elit eros fringilla tellus, eget fringilla odio mi quis tellus. Quisque rhoncus finibus erat, a mattis libero vulputate sit amet. Proin ut tristique leo. Integer interdum, urna nec elementum imperdiet, tortor odio vehicula nisi, ut porttitor libero urna dapibus neque. Sed lacus ex, dignissim nec mauris varius, bibendum elementum nibh. Morbi quis erat at ipsum sollicitudin accumsan nec et ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris et consequat nisi. Sed id sem vitae odio semper sollicitudin. Integer dapibus est vel semper ultrices. Vivamus sagittis lobortis odio, vel tincidunt nisl tempus id. Nullam gravida vestibulum efficitur. Ut sed ligula sit amet quam fermentum efficitur. Vivamus eu sem a ligula suscipit lacinia.</p>

<p>Praesent a dolor finibus, porttitor est in, hendrerit eros. Pellentesque dui mauris, vehicula euismod ex et, tempus viverra metus. Vivamus molestie, erat non consectetur dapibus, sapien magna sollicitudin orci, vitae porta sem tellus nec nulla. Mauris non mauris quis urna vulputate cursus a eget sem. Vestibulum ac urna dictum, aliquet arcu sed, aliquam velit. Sed id bibendum dolor, eget semper tellus. Fusce aliquam ex quis mauris laoreet, et tincidunt sapien feugiat. Pellentesque sapien leo, faucibus non sapien sit amet, tristique tristique dui. Praesent ultrices blandit tellus, ac volutpat neque laoreet eget. Proin lobortis mauris vel sem eleifend sollicitudin. Vestibulum tempor fermentum elit, nec condimentum metus ultrices in. Donec quis laoreet erat, eu lacinia nibh. Nam eleifend neque vel ipsum lacinia venenatis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: HI Mihai, thanks for taking the time to explain this. I can't seem to get this to work in my actual scenario as setting the parent div to height: 100%; seems to have no impact. Is there another way to achieve the desired effect without changing height?

Comment: The div is nested quite deeply, with content above and below. Any suggestions on why height 100% for the parent div does not work?

Comment: height:100% will work only if the parent of the element you set height:100% to has a height set. Try adding 100% to body,html { height: 100% } that might help.

Comment: Im my case, I can't explicitly define a height as it needs to be fluid. I'm guessing this means I can't set it up this way, but I can't think of a different way to achieve this effect without using height. If you have any suggestions, I welcome them. Thanks!